# Return value of a variadic logging probe

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I would like this function to return exactly what it is passed (has passed in as arguments):

```
(defn log [& txts]
  (.log js/console (apply str txts))
  txts)
```

As the moment `txts` is being returned, which is not exactly the same thing as the caller passed in.

Once this question is answered I will have a logging function that is able to be used as a *probe* - able to be wrapped around any existing function call without changing what the program does.

Here's a *REPL friendly* (copy and paste, and the log function altered to work for Clojure) example that shows that logging affects the output:

```
(def infos [{:colour [0,0,139]} {:colour [255,255,0]} {:colour [0,0,0]} {:colour [255,0,0]}])

(defn log [& txts]
  (println (apply str txts))
  txts)

(defn random-colour-logged
  []
  (let [colour-idx (rand-int 4)]
    (log (:colour (get infos colour-idx)))))

(defn random-colour-not-logged
  []
  (let [colour-idx (rand-int 4)]
    (:colour (get infos colour-idx))))

(random-colour-logged)
(random-colour-logged)
(random-colour-not-logged)
(random-colour-not-logged)
```

This is the output I just received:

```
user=> (random-colour-logged)
[255 255 0]
([255 255 0])
user=> (random-colour-logged)
[0 0 139]
([0 0 139])
user=> (random-colour-not-logged)
[255 255 0]
user=> (random-colour-not-logged)
[255 0 0]
```

Comment: Could you add an example - what do you mean by "not exactly the same thing"? This function should return a list of arguments that you pass in.

Answer (score 0):

When you define your function as

```
(defn log [& txts]
  ...
  txts)
```

it means that you can pass any number of arguments and these arguments are then collected in a list txts. Therefore the return value in your case is a list.

So when you call

```
(random-colour-logged)
```

the value of txts is going to be a list of single vector:

```
'([255 255 0])
```

This is happening in your examples (inside your function):

```
user=> (println (apply str '([255 255 0])))
[255 255 0]
```

Try changing your function to

```
(defn log [txt]
  (.log js/console txt)
  txt)
```

and it should work just fine.

**Edit :**
You can also change the  way how you call the log function :

```
(defn random-colour-logged
  []
  (let [colour-idx (rand-int 4)]
    (apply log (:colour (get infos colour-idx)))))
```

This way both - what you log and what the function return will be the same - list of numbers.

Comment: (def big-word "varadic")(log "But then it will no longer be " big-word)

Comment: see my edit. There isn't much more you can do in there if you don't want to implement custom logging for your case.

Comment: There are simpler workarounds than putting in `apply` before the log call. Even so I copy/pasted your `random-colour-logged` - and in the REPL you still see different results for the 'logged' and 'not-logged' calls.

Comment: The practical workaround I'm going to use is just to have a function called `wrap` which is a non-variadic version of `log`. And I will make `log` not return anything.